# Strange behavior observed with Spring 3.1 Controller

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I'm using Spring 3.1 and tiles to develop a MVC app.

I have a JSP page (header.jsp) and 2 controllers (HomeController and SignupController).

The header.jsp is like this:

```
<s:url var="login_url" value="${loginUrl}" />
<s:url var="signup_url" value="${signUpFormUrl}" />
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="${login_url}">Login</a>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="${signup_url}">Signup</a>
```

The HomeController.java is like this (the /login/form URL is configured to be used by spring security as login page):

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
  @RequestMapping({"/", "/home"})
  public String showHomePage(final Map<String, Object> model) {
     return "home";
  }

  @ModelAttribute("loginUrl")
  public String getLoginUrl() {
    return "/login/form";
  }
  ......
}
```

The SignupController.java is like this:

```
@Controller
public class SignupController {
   .....
   @RequestMapping(value = "/signup/form")
   public String signup(@ModelAttribute SignupForm signupForm) {
    return "signup/form";
   }

   @ModelAttribute("signUpFormUrl")
   public String getSignUpFormUrl() {
    return "/signup/form";
   }
   .....
}
```

What's strange is that like it is presented above I got this result when the page is rendered:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="/appContext/login/form">Login</a>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="">Signup</a>
```

So the  ended up with empty href value.

BUT when I moved around the signup controller code regarding the signup (the RequestMapping and the ModelAttribute method) to the home controller, it worked as expected:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="/appContext/login/form">Login</a>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="/appContext/signup/form">Signup</a>
```

Is it possible to use RequestMapping from different Controller inside a same view?

Can someone has a view on what is going on here?

Thanks in advance. I can supply anything other (config?) needed to understand further the problem.

Comment: No you cannot. There is a single controller handling the view and all the properties (model attributes) need to be present. It doesn't scan all controllers and make all the `@ModelAttribute`s available. It just scans the current controller.

Comment: But you can use a ControllerAdvice component to provide modelattributes and other features to all controllers.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! The two above comments pretty much solve my "concern". I was trying to avoid duplicating "magic strings" of request mappings  in my view code by providing their value through model. Deinum reminds me that this is not possible (it is clear from the MVC standpoint). Finally Martin shows me how to the same thing.